# Convert Bitmap tp Image

Tags: c#, emgucv

After flipping a Bitmap I want to put it an ImageBox:

```
//set cam
Mat m = new Mat();
m = capture.QuerySmallFrame();

//Flip picture
Image img = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);

// show it 
imageBox1.Image = img
```

When I run this, I get:

> Can not implicitly convert type `System.Drawing.Image` to `Emgu.CV.IImage`.

Answer (score 1):

The ImageBox.Image expects Emgu.CV.World.IImage, so I'd suggest doing the rotation using IImage's methods and avoiding to convert into System.Drawing.Bitmap altogether. The code below should do that:

```
//Flip picture
var img = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
img = img.Rotate(180, new Bgr(Color.Red)).Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Vertical);
// show it 
imageBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed to `var img = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;` and it did not work still getting the same error !

Comment: I see. My bad. ImageBox is provided by Emgu as well. In that case, the Emgu.CV.World.IImage goes into the imageBox1.Image property. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Well  I tried this and it worked `var img = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
               
                this.imageBox1.Image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(img);`